# /var/cache/apt dir filling with daily pkgcache.bin.xxxyyy files

Tags: apt, disk-usage, cache

I have a headless remote webcam server connected via the mobile telephone network.
Each day at 0625 local time (GMT +12), a new file `pkgcache.bin.xxxyyy` (where xxxyyy are seemingly random letters/numbers) gets added to the `/var/cache/apt/` dir.  This continues until the entire root partition is full and the server locks up.

I understand that this should only happen if `apt-get update` is run but I don't do that.  No one has access to run that command. I do not install any updates on the server once deployed.  At present, the server has no connection to the internet, so these files are generated by the software on the server.

What is worse is that this problem seems to have started itself.  This server has been running since 2014 without issue.  It has started to fill up the cache directory in the last 6 months for no obvious reasons.

I could crontab a job to run `apt-get clean` daily but I would rather find the source of the file.

I checked the "apt" logs.  There are no new entries from when initial installation was done.

Does anyone know why the `/var/cache/apt` directory might be filling with GBs of files?

Alternatively, how can I trace the program that generates the file?

Comment: Try looking at what runs from anacron (/etc/crontab, /etc/cron.d, /etc/cron.daily and so on). Some job there might be calling 'apt-get update' or similar.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the tip @Soren .  There are a lot of parameters and I am going through them.   The one that limits the archive to 500MB doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing some research on this.
It appears that this may be a recognized bug [should clean pkgcache.bin.* and srcpkgcache.bin.*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1045704)

There are differences.

- It appears that running apt-get creates pkgcache.bin.[random]  files
  but I don't run apt-get everyday.

  This problem started spontaneously.

I can't find a command that will allow me to identify the program that is creating these files, but it can only be apt-get.  I don't know what is triggering apt-get to run.

I am going to fix this problem by running apt-get clean as a daily cron jog.  It is a bit like asking the burglar to guard the house. It is not a good answer because it doesn't fix the root cause.